# Heroku app not finding bower components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, heroku, bower, mean-stack

I am trying to deploy my MEAN stack app to Heroku. I have deployed a few apps in the past one of them was a MEAN stack app. The difference is I am not using webpack in this app.

My problem is that when I load my app I get a bunch of errors in the chrome console saying stuff like this:

```
GET https://xxxxxxx-66928.herokuapp.com/bower_components/angular/angular.js 
GET https://fierce-escarpment-66928.herokuapp.com/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css
```

Here is part of my index.html file that I believe to be causing the errors:

```
<html ng-app="app">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>XXX</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Car database">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/style.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>

  <!-- JS libraries -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="./bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="./bower_components/filepicker-js/filepicker.js"></script>
  <script src="./bower_components/angular-filepicker/dist/angular_filepicker.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular files -->
  <script src="./app.js"></script>

  <script src="./controllers/addCarController.js"></script>
  <script src="./controllers/galleryController.js"></script>
  <script src="./controllers/detailController.js"></script>
  <script src="./controllers/userController.js"></script>
  <script src="./services/auth_service.js"></script>
  <script src="./services/error_service.js"></script>
  <script src="./services/car_service.js"></script>

</head>
```

I added this into my package.json file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install"
   }
```

Any help on getting these errors resolved would be awesome thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `postinstall` in `package.json` file to:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I figured out what was wrong (with the help of Heroku support). When bower components got installed on Heroku it was installing to the root directory of my application instead of my app folder. I had to create a .bowerrc file and set the directory path I wanted it to install like this:

```
{
  "directory" : "app/bower_components"
}
```

Using `heroku run bash` command I was able to see the file structure and see that bower_components was not where it needed to be in my app.